# Firebase Mapping Many to Many

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have the following problem while trying to find the best data structure in firebase cloud firestore (NoSql) for a group travel app.

To put it as simple as I can... We have users. A user creates a new trip where he can include his friends. Those friends would also see the trip they where added to.

In a relational data base, we could represent this with 3 tables: Users - UsersTrips - Trips, where UsersTrips would have foreign key to UserId and TripId.

How can I map this problem to NoSql data base? In particulary, to firestore? I guess this is a many-to-many problem, because a trip could hold many users and a user can participate in many trips.

I had a wrong aproach of having a document "trips" that holds an array of the uids of users, but I find it a little bit strange.

[image]

Comment: Storing UIDs of users in `travelers` array does seem valid. You can query trips of a user and also implement security rules around this. You can then query all the users of a trip because you have their UIDs.  What issues are you facing with this (like implementing any specific functionality)?

Comment: "I had a wrong aproach" and " I find it a little bit strange" are hard to help with. In general though: NoSQL data modeling depends on the use-cases of your app more than anything else. If this is new to you, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Both really helpfull. What I ment by "a bit strange" is that for getting a users trips I will have to query throught each array of uids for every stored trip. This is what I find odd, but again, Im pretty new with NoSQL.

Comment: Your question is focused on how to best design a NoSQL database to implement a M:N relationship, and this question would be better suited for the [Software Engineering forums](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?